# Check number in another file if in range using shell script and output all information for that match

Tags: awk

I have two input files

```
File A

chr1    1167639 0
chrX    114868305   14
chr1    1167653 0
chr11   62389325    2
chr9    140127768   17

File B

chr10   73082492    73082831 SLC29A3
chr11   46332562    46332760 CREB3L1
chr11   62389317    62389439 B3GAT3
chrX    22056566    22056675 PHEX
chrX    114868291   114868413 PLS3
```

This is my desired Output

```
chrX    114868305   14 chrX    114868291   114868413   PLS3
chr11   62389325    2  chr11   62389317    62389439    B3GAT3
```

What I would like is: To find the column 1 element of File A in column 1 of File B. If the string is the same, take the number of column 2 of File A and check if it is included in the range of numbers of column 2 and 3 of File B. If it is included, print the line of File A and File B in a single line in the output.

Comment: I guess `paste 3850.txt BED.txt` fails to solve your problem? If yes, please give a more complex example.

Comment: Both your files appear to be delimited by some kind of whitespace (spaces or possibly tabs) so how did you decide to use `-F', +'`?

Comment: @steeldriver I see. In my case these are tab delimited so I should awk -F"\t" and not comma

Comment: @Quasimodo This is my lack of clarification: The 3850.txt file contains 4541 entries. The BED.txt contains 505 entries. Both are sorted. Each value in 3850.txt should be checked against all ranges in BED.txt to see if it falls into at least one range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    ++cnt[$1]
    beg[$1,cnt[$1]] = $2
    end[$1,cnt[$1]] = $3
    val[$1,cnt[$1]] = $0
    next
}
$1 in cnt {
    for (i=1; i<=cnt[$1]; i++) {
        if ( (beg[$1,i] <= $2) && ($2 <= end[$1,i]) ) {
            print $0, val[$1,i]
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk fileB fileA
chrX    114868305   14  chrX    114868291   114868413 PLS3
chr11   62389325    2   chr11   62389317    62389439 B3GAT3
```

The above assumes you want tab-delimited output, if you don't then get rid of `BEGIN { OFS="\t" }` and if you want it visually tabular then pipe it to `column -t`.